# Apache Artemis 2.17 "Error: Could not find or load main class Artemis Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Artemis"

Tags: activemq-artemis

Artemis was already installed and I was about to test a broker. After I ran the following command `artemis.cmd run` I received the error message:

```
Artemis was unexpected at this time.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is how I did it.

```
C:\temp\Apache Artemis 2.17.0\apache-artemis-2.17.0-bin\apache-artemis-2.17.0\bin\mybroker\bin>artemis-service.exe start

2021-06-25 14:10:35,589 INFO  - Starting the service with id 'artemis-mybroker-0.0.0.0'
```

```
C:\temp\Apache Artemis 2.17.0\apache-artemis-2.17.0-bin\apache-artemis-2.17.0\bin\mybroker\bin>artemis-service.exe test

2021-06-25 14:12:31,503 INFO  - Starting C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.2\bin\java.exe  "-Xbootclasspath/a:C:\temp\Apache Artemis 2.17.0\apache-artemis-2.17.0-bin\apache-artemis-2.17.0\lib\jboss-logmanager-2.1.10.Final.jar;C:\temp\Apache Artemis 2.17.0\apache-artemis-2.17.0-bin\apache-artemis-2.17.0\lib\wildfly-common-1.5.2.Final.jar" -XX:+UseParallelGC -Xms512M -Xmx1024M -classpath "C:\temp\Apache Artemis 2.17.0\apache-artemis-2.17.0-bin\apache-artemis-2.17.0\lib\artemis-boot.jar" "-Dartemis.home=C:\temp\Apache Artemis 2.17.0\apache-artemis-2.17.0-bin\apache-artemis-2.17.0" "-Dartemis.instance=C:\temp\Apache Artemis 2.17.0\apache-artemis-2.17.0-bin\apache-artemis-2.17.0\bin\mybroker" "-Ddata.dir=C:\temp\Apache Artemis 2.17.0\apache-artemis-2.17.0-bin\apache-artemis-2.17.0\bin\mybroker\data" "-Dartemis.instance.etc=C:\temp\Apache Artemis 2.17.0\apache-artemis-2.17.0-bin\apache-artemis-2.17.0\bin\mybroker\etc" -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager -Dlogging.configuration=file:/C:/temp/Apache%%20Artemis%%202.17.0/apache-artemis-2.17.0-bin/apache-artemis-2.17.0/bin/mybroker/etc//logging.properties "-Djava.security.auth.login.config=C:\temp\Apache Artemis 2.17.0\apache-artemis-2.17.0-bin\apache-artemis-2.17.0\bin\mybroker\etc\login.config" -Dhawtio.disableProxy=true -Dhawtio.realm=activemq -Dhawtio.offline="true" -Dhawtio.role=amq -Dhawtio.rolePrincipalClasses=org.apache.activemq.artemis.spi.core.security.jaas.RolePrincipal -Djolokia.policyLocation=file:/C:/temp/Apache%%20Artemis%%202.17.0/apache-artemis-2.17.0-bin/apache-artemis-2.17.0/bin/mybroker/etc//jolokia-access.xml org.apache.activemq.artemis.boot.Artemis run

2021-06-25 14:12:31,536 INFO  - Started process 7424
2021-06-25 14:12:32,572 INFO  - Stopping artemis-mybroker-0.0.0.0
2021-06-25 14:12:32,579 INFO  - Started process 668

Error: Could not find or load main class Artemis
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Artemis
```

```
C:\temp\Apache Artemis 2.17.0\apache-artemis-2.17.0-bin\apache-artemis-2.17.0\bin\mybroker\bin>artemis.cmd run

Artemis was unexpected at this time.
```

Comment: Why are you starting the ActiveMQ Artemis Windows service (which starts the broker in the background) and then trying to start the broker directly? Also, what does the broker log report?

Comment: Hi Justin, How can I start to use Artemis first? I am new to use this application.

Comment: Make sure there are no instance of the broke running and then run `artemis.cmd run`.

Comment: Thanks Justin. it is working. I forget to run before it starts Windows service.